# Detect UTF-16 support, and replace with images otherwise

Tags: html, utf-16

As part of an HUD I'm designing, I'd like to use this symbol: 🏥

Since my site serves files in Windows-1252, any characters outside the 0-255 range are represented as `&#x____;`, with appropriate hex digits filling in the blank. In this case: `&#x1f3e5;`

However, when testing this out I noticed that IE can render the symbol, but Chrome cannot. I guess this question is this: What does IE have that Chrome doesn't, is there any way to give Chrome the ability to render these symbols, and if not can I detect that and replace it with an image?

Comment: Both browsers have that, but they might just use a different typeface to display it. Hint: It's not only the browsers but also the operating system. http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/ - http://i.imgur.com/Cr0lltY.png

Comment: You could use an icon font instead, with a meaningful fallback, like H. (I can't see it either on account of not having good fonts. Oops.)

Answer (score 3):

It is not only enough to properly encode the charset information inside your HTML document, but on the other hand, the browser must be able to use the right encoding (check the settings) and it must be able to display it. In the following example, the browser is properly configured, it is just that the operating system is not able to use UTF-8 characters:

[image]

Comment: @Kolink: If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the large tick mark under the question's score.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I (mis-)understood it also is a font issue, where smart browsers possibly substitute the missing char by one out of another font. The newer browsers can also be served fonts from the server. Maybe that helps.

I hope you get a better answer.